# Should I create a new file for save data with python?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, authentication, client-server

It may seem like a stupid question, but I really can't find information about this in google.

I am trying to develop a server-client application in python language, I am searching for a correct way to save data on a computer.

I have a client, that when he click the "Register" button I want that his computer will save the information and he can auto-login when he secondly entered the program.

Should I make a new file, save it with the data in the computer and then, load it again and read the data? I really don't know is this is the correct way.

Comment: You need to store the data *somewhere*, and a file could be a good place. You could also store it in a database (if you use it), or in gconf/dconf/windows registry (depending on platform)... You do need to make sure that other users can't read the file (or db, or reg entry), though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches to this problem. You could save the credentials/token/.. to the local disk, but keep in mind that in some cases this might be consindered a security risk. If you do so you should probably store it under user's home folder to keep it from other (non-admin/root users) at least.

You could also store it and encrypt it with e "Master password" (like Firefox does if you enable it).

Or you could connect to a 3rd party authentication server and store your information there. It all depends on the use case you are implementing as well as the complexity required.

Comment: What is the saftest way to store data to the local disk? in what paths the client can't read the data? Thanks a lot for this answer.

Comment: The idea is to isolate the people, who can access the data the best you can. On linux that would be the home dir of the user. On Windows, IIRC the AppData is the place to put such things (or the registry of the user as @Carpetsmoker suggested). There were some differences about Local and [Roaming folder](https://askleo.com/whats-the-appdata-roaming-folder/), which might be relevant if you are in a Domain environment.